# No speedup for n-ary search using OpenMP

Tags: c, search, parallel-processing, openmp

I am writing code for n-ary search i.e splitting search space into n parts.
When compared parallel code with the code without OpenMP directives i.e serial execution , I observed that parallel code is slower than serial code many times. After executing both programs many times I saw little speedup in parallel code but not every time. This is maybe due to cache hierarchy. I am running program on quad-core processor with 4GB RAM.

According to answer on [No speedup with OpenMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38630633/no-speedup-with-openmp) Memory bound performance and Load balancing is not applicable for small problems such as with array `SIZE 100`. I have not used any synchronization. I also tried increasing array size to 10000000 but output is not always faster with parallel code. Many times serial code beats parallel code.

According to http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/omp-loop.html The implicit barrier at the end of a work sharing construct can be cancelled with a `nowait` clause. I tried adding `nowait` clause also I also tried schedule(dynamic) and schedule(auto) referring to https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/openmp-loop-scheduling  but still same problem.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define SIZE 100
#define NUM_THREADS 4

int* a;
int num;


void nary(int num)
{
    int found = 0, low = 0, high = SIZE, step;
    int i = 0;
    while(!found && low <= high)
    {
        step = (high-low)/NUM_THREADS;
        printf("Low :- %d\tHigh :- %d\tStep :- %d\n", low,high,step);
        printf("\n");

        #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(NUM_THREADS) shared(low,high,step)
        for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
        {
            printf("First element :- %d by thread :- %d\n", a[low+step*i],omp_get_thread_num());
            if (a[low+step*i] == num)
            {
                found = 1;
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
        /* First block */
        if (a[low+step] > num)
        {
            high = low + step - 1;
            printf("First \nLow :- %d \nHigh :- %d\n\n",low,high);
        }

        /* Last block */
        else if (a[low+step*(NUM_THREADS-1)] < num)
        {
            low = low + step * (NUM_THREADS-1) + 1;
            printf("Last\nLow :- %d \nHigh :- %d\n\n",low,high);
        }
        /* Middle blocks */
         else{
            #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(NUM_THREADS) schedule(static) shared(low,high,step)
            for (i = 1; i < (NUM_THREADS-1); ++i)
            {
                if (a[low+step*i] < num && a[low+step*(i+1)] > num)
                {
                    low = low + step*i + 1;
                    high = low + step*(i+1) - 1;
                }
            }
            printf("middle\nLow :- %d \nHigh :- %d\n\n",low,high);
        }
    }
    if (found == 1)
    {
        printf("Element found\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Element Not found\n");
    }

}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int startTime = omp_get_wtime();

    /* Dynamically allocate memory using malloc() */
    a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * SIZE);
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = i;

    }

    printf("Enter the element to be searched :- \n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    nary(num);


    printf("\nExecution time :- %f\n", omp_get_wtime()-startTime);
    return 0;
}
```

**Parallel Execution Output:**

```
Enter the element to be searched :- 
20
Low :- 0    High :- 100 Step :- 25

First element :- 0 by thread :- 0
First element :- 50 by thread :- 2
First element :- 25 by thread :- 1
First element :- 75 by thread :- 3

First 
Low :- 0 
High :- 24

Low :- 0    High :- 24  Step :- 6

First element :- 6 by thread :- 1
First element :- 18 by thread :- 3
First element :- 0 by thread :- 0
First element :- 12 by thread :- 2

Last
Low :- 19 
High :- 24

Low :- 19   High :- 24  Step :- 1

First element :- 20 by thread :- 1
First element :- 21 by thread :- 2
First element :- 19 by thread :- 0
First element :- 22 by thread :- 3

middle
Low :- 19 
High :- 24

Element found

Execution time :- 26.824379
```

**Serial Execution Output:**

```
Enter the element to be searched :- 
20
Low :- 0    High :- 100 Step :- 25

First element :- 0 by thread :- 0
First element :- 25 by thread :- 0
First element :- 50 by thread :- 0
First element :- 75 by thread :- 0

First 
Low :- 0 
High :- 24

Low :- 0    High :- 24  Step :- 6

First element :- 0 by thread :- 0
First element :- 6 by thread :- 0
First element :- 12 by thread :- 0
First element :- 18 by thread :- 0

Last
Low :- 19 
High :- 24

Low :- 19   High :- 24  Step :- 1

First element :- 19 by thread :- 0
First element :- 20 by thread :- 0
First element :- 21 by thread :- 0
First element :- 22 by thread :- 0

middle
Low :- 19 
High :- 24

Element found

Execution time :- 4.349347
```

What can be the reason behind this? Is this because there are many conditional statements in the code or the for loop inside the conditional block?

Comment: It takes time to start a new thread. The amount of work performed in parallel must be large enough to earn that back.

Comment: The code seems to be entirely C, any reason you chose to tag C++?

Comment: @BoPersson I tried with array size 10000 but same results

Comment: @Zulan changed it to C but OpenMP also works with C++

Comment: It also works with Fortran.. C and C++ are very different languages. Choose the applicable one. That can be C++ and not C if you want https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281197/re-tagging-c-questions-as-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many small and big issues in your approach.

First and foremost, binary search is very fast. It requires only log<sub>2</sub>(n) iterations in the worst case. Even for one trillion elements to search through, that's only 40 iterations! Each iteration is extremely simple, basically needs only a single memory access. So we are talking about a few microseconds search time in the worst case for a large dataset. That is, of course, without polluting the stuff with `printf`.

On the other hand, spawning a thread takes about 10 microseconds according to [some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27764581/620382) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18275460/620382). So even for a perfect scaling implementation, there is no realistic chance for any performance improvement based on parallelizing a **single** search.

Looking at your specific code, you create two parallel regions per iteration. Each thread has only a tiny amount of work, compared to the overhead of a parallel region and a `omp for` worksharing construct (which may vary greatly depending on implementation and OS).

I find the mixing of arity and `NUM_THREADS` problematic. Your update step consists of two serial executions and the remaining `NUM_THREADS-2` intervals are checked by `NUM_THREADS` threads... So for `NUM_THREADS=4`, even with perfect parallel execution, you are only reducing the time from 4 interval checks to 3 interval checks, a 1.3x speedup on the update step.

Further, your code contains a severe race conditions: Modifying `low` in the second parallel loop is a very bad idea, given that other threads are concurrently checking their interval based on `low`.

If you want to practically improve performance of searching in sorted contiguous data, then check out [these slides](https://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~rgemulla/publications/schlegel09search.pptx). If you want to speed up your application using OpenMP / threads, you should probably approach this on a more coarse grained level.

Comment: I am unable to understand concepts from the slides you suggested. race condition can be avoided using `shared(low,high,step)` .Can you please suggest changes in the code?

Comment: The `shared` declaration changes nothing, the variables are implicitly shared because they are declared outside of the parallel region. In fact only shared variables can have race conditions. I'm afraid explaining the basics of OpenMP is beyond the scope of an answer on SO. I cannot suggest changes to the code because, as I wrote in the answer, it is futile to try to improve the performance of a single search with thread based parallelization.